# Problem to see consequence for convex function

Tags: real-analysis

Let $U\subset\mathbb{R}^n$ and consider a smooth function $H\colon U\to\mathbb{R}$ with a unique minimum $u_\infty\in U$ and with $\lambda$-convexity, i.e., $\nabla^2f\geq\lambda\textbf{1}$ uniformly on $U$ for some $\lambda>0$.

It is said [here, on  page 6](https://www2.karlin.mff.cuni.cz/%7Ekaplicky/pages/pages/2020l/matthes_entropymethods.pdf) that, by convexity,
$$
H(u)-H(u_\infty)\leq\nabla H(u)\cdot(u-u_\infty)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\lVert u-u_\infty\rVert^2\leq \frac{1}{2\lambda}\lVert \nabla H(u)\rVert ^2
$$

How to see the second inequality?

I cannot see it.

---

Answer (score 1):

So your problem is to prove $f(x) - f(x^*) \le \frac{1}{2\lambda}\|\nabla f(x)\|^2$.
By the strong convexity, we have
$$f(x^*) =\inf_y f(y) \ge \inf_y\{ f(x) + \nabla f(x)(y-x) + \frac{1}{2}\lambda \|y-x\|^2 \}\\
\ge f(x) + \inf_y\{ \nabla f(x) (y-x) + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|y-x\|^2 \}$$
We can let $y-x = z$, and the minimum of $\nabla f(x) z + \frac{\lambda}{2}\|z\|^2$ is $z=-\frac{\nabla f(x)}{\lambda}$, which gives the value $-\frac{\|\nabla f(x)\|^2}{2\lambda}$.

QED

Comment: If you set $z=y-x$, then you have to find the minimum of $\nabla f(x)z+\frac{\lambda}{2}\lVert z\rVert^2$, don't you?

Comment: I do not understand the inequality
$$
\inf_y\{f(x)+\nabla f(x)(y-x)+\frac{1}{2}\lambda\lVert y-x\rVert^2\}\geq f(x)+\inf_y\{\nabla f(x)(y-x)-\frac{\lambda}{2}\lVert y-x\rVert^2\}.
$$
Why is $y$ the variable to take the infimum of and why can I put the $f(x)$ out of the infimum?

Comment: The inequality means for any fixed $x$, we can change $y$ to make the equation minimum. So it does not take matter with $x$. If you like, you can still use $y$ and the minimum of the quadratic equation of $y$ is taking $y=-\nabla f(x)/\lambda + x$.